# What does $o(x^4)$ mean in the following series expansion?

Tags: taylor-expansion

Given $$f(x)=\sin^2(x)-x^2e^{-x}$$ I know the series expansion for $\sin(x)$ and $e^{-x}$ and so I wrote: $$f(x)=(x-x^3/3!+x^5/5!-....)^2-x^2(1-x+x^2/2!-x^3/3!+....)$$ I am finding it difficult to proceed beyond this point as I'm having trouble in squarign the series $\sin(x)$. However the author, further writes $$f(x)=x^2-x^4/3+o(x^5)-x^2+x^3-x^4/2+o(x^4)=x^3-5x^4/6+o(x^4)$$
What does $o(x^5)$ and $o(x^4)$ mean and what rules should one follow in order to determmine the power of $x$ that goes in the expression $o(x^n)$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation

Comment: Note: we are talking about $o(x^4)$ as $x \to 0$.

Comment: @vadim123 I went over the link and found that my problem is related to something known as Infinitesimal Asymptotics. Could you give me a reference that contains more examples on how to write these expressions?

Comment: As to which power goes into little o: the largest one you have in the explicit part (given that you also have all smaller ones in he explicit part)